# Using Gmail API with Python, searching messages return Requested entity was not found

Tags: python, django, google-api, gmail-api

I am working in gmail api using python and django. In this case I need to work in the backend offline authentication. After create the url to auth the backend and create the credentials I need to get specific message with the id message.

This the code:

```
   state = request.GET['state']
    flow = google_auth_oauthlib.flow.Flow.from_client_secrets_file( client_secrets_file='credentials.json', scopes='https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.metadata https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email openid https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.readonly https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.compose',state=state)
    flow.redirect_uri = 'https://domian.com/auth/oauth'
    authorization_response = request.build_absolute_uri()
    flow.fetch_token(authorization_response=authorization_response, client_secret='<client_secret>', code=request.GET['code'])
    request.session['credentials'] = {
        'token': credentials.token,
        'refresh_token': credentials.refresh_token,
        'token_uri': credentials.token_uri,
        'client_id': credentials.client_id,
        'client_secret': credentials.client_secret,
        'scopes': credentials.scopes
    }                                                                                                         

service =  build('gmail', 'v1', credentials=credentials)
results = service.users().messages().get(userId='me', id='<id>', format='minimal').execute()
```

Django return:
HttpError at /auth/oauth
<HttpError 404 when requesting https://gmail.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/me/messages/1273369159314488?format=minimal&alt=json returned "Requested entity was not found.">

But the id message exist and is correct.
Even I use others endpoints like labels and works good the query.

Somene have any suggestions?
Regards

Comment: Are you using a service account?

Comment: If you do - you need to use impersonation to allow the service account to access your messages.